# Navigation property no more working after migration of breeze 1.4.2

Tags: breeze, durandal

I work with asp.net mvc with Durandal & breeze templates.

I have the following code-first classes:

1st scenario:

```
public class Transport
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? SenderId { get; set; }
    public virtual SendRecv Sender { get; set; }
}

public class SendRecv
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<Transport> Transports { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can easily get all my related transports from my observable of type `SendRecv`:

```
if (sendRecvs()[i].transports().length > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

**The problem:** I add a new reference to the same entity `SendRecv` in my `Transport` entity like this:

2nd scenario:

```
public class Transport
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? SenderId { get; set; }  
    public int? ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public virtual SendRecv Sender { get; set; }
    public virtual SendRecv Receiver { get; set; }
}
```

**Then I cannot get my related transports anymore! The navigation property named `transport` from my `SendRecv` entity does not exists anymore.**

This don't work anymore:

```
if (sendRecvs()[i].transports().length > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

PS: I'm pretty sure this worked before the migration of breeze to 1.4.2

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `expand`?

Comment: Yes `.expand('transports')`

Comment: So - does that property show up as null if you console.log the backing store of the Breeze object?  I'm not sure if caps sensitivity would play a role.  Or does it not exist whatsoever?

Comment: This property `transports` is no more listed! Caps sensitivity is not the problem because if I play the first scenario as described above it works.

Comment: Could you please update the original post with both the Transport and SendRecv classes that you're currently working with?  Are you sure your model itself hasn't been changed?  I don't think this should be a problem whatsoever with Breeze.  Be sure to look at your database tables and see if they look OK too.

Comment: My model is showed in my question (removed some extra properties for clarity). I'm sure my model hasn't changed. As I explained in my question: the first scenario is working, the second (with double reference SendRecv) isn't working.

Comment: We'll try to repro and let you know what we find.

Comment: My apologies, it seems I missed the fluent API as suggested in the answer by @sbelini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you only want one collection of Transport in SendRecv.
If so, try this (using fluent API):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
   modelBuilder.Entity<SendRecv>()
      .HasMany(c => c.Transports)
      .WithRequired(c => c.Sender)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

   modelBuilder.Entity<SendRecv>()
      .HasMany(c => c.Transports)
      .WithRequired(c => c.Receiver)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Now, if you want 2 Transport lists (i.e. Transports1 and Transports2) then try:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
   modelBuilder.Entity<SendRecv>()
      .HasMany(c => c.Transports1)
      .WithRequired(c => c.Sender)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

   modelBuilder.Entity<SendRecv>()
      .HasMany(c => c.Transports2)
      .WithRequired(c => c.Receiver)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```