# Fluent API - collection navigation

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am working with asp.net mvc with durandal & **breeze** templates.

I have the following classes (removed some properties for clarity):

```
public class Rolling
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<Itinerary> Itineraries { get; set; }
}

public class Itinerary
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? VehicleId { get; set; }                
    public int? TrailerId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Rolling Vehicle { get; set; }
    public virtual Rolling Trailer { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Rolling>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Itineraries)
            .WithOptional(c => c.Vehicle)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Rolling>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Itineraries)
            .WithOptional(c => c.Trailer)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Please note the order of declaring these fluent APIs.

At runtime, I perform a breeze query client side to get all the rolling entities:

```
var query = entityQuery.from('Rollings')
                       .where(predicates)
                       .orderBy(orderyByClause)
                       .expand('Itineraries');
```

For each one, I check the itineraries collection property:

```
rollings()[0].itineraries
```

I noted that I only retrieved itineraries for rollings where the `Trailer` property of `Itinerary` is filled. None of the rollings where the `Vehicle` property of `Itinerary` is filled.

**BUT** if I swap fluent API like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Rolling>()
                    .HasMany(c => c.Itineraries)
                    .WithOptional(c => c.Trailer)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Rolling>()
                    .HasMany(c => c.Itineraries)
                    .WithOptional(c => c.Vehicle)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Then I noted that I only retrieved itineraries for rollings where the `Vehicle` property of `Itinerary` is filled. None of the rollings where the `Trailer` property of `Itinerary` is filled.

Is this a normal behaviour? A bug?

Thanks for investigating.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a follow up question for [Navigation property no more working after migration of breeze 1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847327/navigation-property-no-more-working-after-migration-of-breeze-1-4-2).

I was able to verify the behavior you described. 
I also verified that this is the EF behavior by running the query on the server:

```
var rolling = mgr.Context.Rollings.Include("Itineraries").First();
var itineraries = mgr.Context.Itineraries.Local;
```

You will notice that itineraries will only have Itineraries with either Vehicle or Trailer filled (depending on the fluent API order of definitions).

It looks like a bug to me, but an Entity Framework bug (not Breeze's bug).

I think Microsoft will have a better saying in this, so posted your question at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7438371d-1072-4a9a-aab8-d12842493066/possible-bug-include-not-working-properly.